# Why am I getting an exception error using MIPS Assembly when using read_string?

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I am getting Exception Error Occurred at PC=0x00000000 when running the example at http://www.tfinley.net/notes/cps104/mips.html  I am using the QtSpim emulator in Linux.

Any ideas on what may be wrong with this code?

```
    .data
theString:
    .space 64
    .text
main:
    li      $v0, 8
    la      $a0, theString
    li      $a1, 64
    syscall
    jr      $ra
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce with QtSpim 9.1.12 on Windows. Try using "Reinitialize and Load File" instead of "Load File" if you've made changes in the code since you first tried to run it.

Comment: Hmmm no luck.   I'll install another QtSpim version or try on my Windows computer.

Comment: Your code is correct and will not fault, `QtSpim` does set up `$ra` in most cases. But, I'd change the `jr` into `li $v0,10`/`syscall` to do a clean exit. IIRC, `mars` doesn't set `$ra`. I much prefer the `mars` simulator: http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/ It is easier to use, has better diagnostics and single-step and setting breakpoints on code is easier